# Java / Swing / WebcamCapture : When I disable a JLabel, an other image appears

Tags: java, swing, webcam

I come to you because I have a strange issue, for which I don't find any solution...

I build an application using a webcam, in order to take some photographs.

I use WebcamCapture to do that, and I don't encounter any issues with it.

The only "weird" thing that happens is the following :

- I use a JDialog in which I make photograph. In its JFrame parent, I display those photographs in JLabel.
- Then, i need to disable those JLabel, and I do that by calling a method which disable all components. The weird thing is, when I disable JLabel, the JLabel display **the last image capture by the webcam**. Not the last photographs, but really the last captured image.

It's seems that BufferedImage (used by WebcamPanel) are linked to the issue.

Here is the SSCE :

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.border.Border;

import com.github.sarxos.webcam.Webcam;
import com.github.sarxos.webcam.WebcamPanel;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class CameraFrame extends JFrame implements ActionListener{

    public Webcam webcam;
    Boolean enabled = true;
    CameraFrame frame;

    private JButton btnSaveVerso;
    private JLabel lblVerso;

    private JButton btnEnable;
    private JButton btnQuit;
    private JPanel mainPanel;
    private WebcamPanel streamPanel;

    public static void main(String[] args){
        CameraFrame frame = new CameraFrame();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public CameraFrame() {

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.HIDE_ON_CLOSE);
                setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                setResizable(false);
                setMinimumSize(new Dimension(800, 600));
                setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800,600));
                buildPanel();
                setContentPane(mainPanel);
            }
        });
    }

    public void buildPanel() {
        mainPanel = new JPanel();
        mainPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(mainPanel, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));

        Border blackline = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black, 1, true);

        webcam = Webcam.getDefault();
        webcam.open();

        streamPanel = new WebcamPanel(webcam);
        streamPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(webcam.getViewSize()));
        streamPanel.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(webcam.getViewSize()));

        btnSaveVerso = new JButton("Take pic");
        btnSaveVerso.setActionCommand("take");
        btnSaveVerso.addActionListener(this);

        lblVerso = new JLabel("Here will be the pic taken by the camera");
        lblVerso.setBorder(blackline);

        btnEnable = new JButton("Disable");
        btnEnable.setActionCommand("disable");
        btnEnable.addActionListener(this);

        btnQuit = new JButton("Quit");
        btnQuit.setActionCommand("quit");
        btnQuit.addActionListener(this);

        mainPanel.add(streamPanel);
        mainPanel.add(btnSaveVerso);
        mainPanel.add(lblVerso);
        mainPanel.add(btnEnable);
        mainPanel.add(btnQuit);

    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(final ActionEvent e) {
        Thread newThread = new Thread(){
            public void run(){
                if(e.getActionCommand().equals("take")){
                    ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(webcam.getImage().getScaledInstance(100, 150, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH ));
                    lblVerso.setIcon(new ImageIcon(icon.getImage()));
                    lblVerso.revalidate();
                    lblVerso.repaint();
                }
                else if(e.getActionCommand().equals("disable")){
                    if(enabled){
                        lblVerso.setEnabled(false);
                        enabled = false;
                        btnEnable.setText("Enable");
                    }
                    else{
                        lblVerso.setEnabled(true);
                        enabled = true;
                        btnEnable.setText("Disable");
                    }
                }
            }
        };
        newThread.run();
        if(e.getActionCommand().equals("quit")){
            webcam.close();
            this.setVisible(false);
        }
    }
}
```

I hope you will compile it without issues. Don't forget to link the [librairies](http://dl.free.fr/j726MO5d5).

Thanks in advance

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Where is it? There is no link in your edit.

Comment: most probably not: if you need to zip it, chances are that you violate one of _S_ :-)

Comment: -1 it's _your_ job to extract the misbehaviour into the smallest possible unit ... typically, that's 50 - 100 lines. Refactor, mock, whatever is needed but _do_ it, no way around most probably nobody else will do it for you ;-) Without the answer is so near to un-answerable that it is in danger of being closed (fingers itching ... but still under control, barely)

Comment: okay, so it's your job to find the difference between the small example and the big example, that causes the error - not a big problem, it's only about 1000 lines :-) That's one of the points in stripping it down to about 50/100 lines: in doing so, you isolate the cause such reducing complexity and coupling to unrelated bits, making it easier for the outsider as well as for yourself to see what exactly goes wrong - and often you can even fix it yourself.

Comment: SSCCE posted. How to use it ? Simply link librairies and launch it (works well for me). Then, take a picture by pressing "Take picture button". You need to disable the label by pressing "Disable" to see what is my problem. To close the frame, click Quit (and NOT the red cross), cause i close the camera in the action listener of Quit button.

Comment: I succeeded to find the same issue. Now when you press Disable, the last pictures taken by the camera appears (in grey). And when you press Enable, the first pictures appears. To do that, I replace a BufferedImage by a "normal" Image. So i think that BufferedImage are the sources of my issue. But I don't see how i can change my code to do it works well...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally resolved the problem : you simply need to close the webcam after each pictures, as follows :

```
BufferedImage picture = webcam.getImage();
webcam.close();
webcam.open();

... Do what you need with picture
```

(You don't even need to convert BufferedImage picture in an other type.)

Comment: +1 for posting the solution - glad you found it (wasn't soo bad to produce that sscce, was it :-)

Comment: In fact. I'm working on a big project, so for me nine classes was very small ! Thanks to have insist.